# Выбрать значения из массива объектов на основе другого массива Javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов и массив

```js
const map = ["_id", "name", "email", "balance"];

const users = [{
    _id: "5d220b10e8265cc978e2586b",
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2853.33,
    age: 20,
    name: "Buckner Osborne",
    gender: "male",
    company: "EMPIRICA",
    email: "bucknerosborne@empirica.com",
    phone: "+1 (850) 411-2997",
    registered: "2018-08-13T04:28:45 -03:00",
    nestedField: {
      total: 300
    }
  },
  {
    _id: "5d220b10144ef972f6c2b332",
    isActive: true,
    balance: 1464.63,
    age: 38,
    name: "Rosalie Smith",
    gender: "female",
    company: "KATAKANA",
    email: "rosaliesmith@katakana.com",
    phone: "+1 (943) 463-2496",
    registered: "2016-12-09T05:15:34 -02:00",
    nestedField: {
      total: 400
    }
  },
  {
    _id: "5d220b1083a0494655cdecf6",
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2823.39,
    age: 40,
    name: "Estrada Davenport",
    gender: "male",
    company: "EBIDCO",
    email: "estradadavenport@ebidco.com",
    phone: "+1 (890) 461-2088",
    registered: "2016-03-04T03:36:38 -02:00",
    nestedField: {
      total: 200
    }
  }
];
```

Нужно получить значения из объектов массива users только те, где ключи совпадают с элементами первого массива map.

Получить нужно такой массив объектов

```js
[
  {
    _id: "5d220b10e8265cc978e2586b",
    balance: 2853.33,
    name: "Buckner Osborne",
    email: "bucknerosborne@empirica.com"
  },
  {
    _id: "5d220b10144ef972f6c2b332",
    balance: 1464.63,
    name: "Rosalie Smith",
    email: "rosaliesmith@katakana.com"
  },
  {
    _id: "5d220b1083a0494655cdecf6",
    balance: 2823.39,
    name: "Estrada Davenport",
    email: "estradadavenport@ebidco.com"
  }
];
```

Comment: Так вроде бы каждый элемент массива `users` удовлетворяет условию *где ключи совпадают с элементами первого массива map*.

Comment: нужно выбрать значения ключей объекта, которые совпадают с элементами массива

Comment: _id: "5d220b1083a0494655cdecf6", balance: 2823.39, name: "Estrada Davenport", email: "estradadavenport@ebidco.com",

Comment: Получить в каком виде, такого же массива объектов ?

Comment: Все равно не понятно. Покажите, что должно получиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так ?

```js
const map = ["_id", "name", "email", "balance"];

const users = [{
    _id: "5d220b10e8265cc978e2586b",
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2853.33,
    age: 20,
    name: "Buckner Osborne",
    gender: "male",
    company: "EMPIRICA",
    email: "bucknerosborne@empirica.com",
    phone: "+1 (850) 411-2997",
    registered: "2018-08-13T04:28:45 -03:00",
    nestedField: {
      total: 300
    }
  },
  {
    _id: "5d220b10144ef972f6c2b332",
    isActive: true,
    balance: 1464.63,
    age: 38,
    name: "Rosalie Smith",
    gender: "female",
    company: "KATAKANA",
    email: "rosaliesmith@katakana.com",
    phone: "+1 (943) 463-2496",
    registered: "2016-12-09T05:15:34 -02:00",
    nestedField: {
      total: 400
    }
  },
  {
    _id: "5d220b1083a0494655cdecf6",
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2823.39,
    age: 40,
    name: "Estrada Davenport",
    gender: "male",
    company: "EBIDCO",
    email: "estradadavenport@ebidco.com",
    phone: "+1 (890) 461-2088",
    registered: "2016-03-04T03:36:38 -02:00",
    nestedField: {
      total: 200
    }
  }
];

const res = users.map(u => map.reduce((a, e) => {
  a[e] = u[e];
  return a;
}, {}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: да, спасибо большое